# Android-Problem in Menu of Activity in Activity Group

Tags: android, android-activity, activitygroup

I have used a technique (http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity) 
to develop an app where I have 3 tabs and each tab has its own ActivityGroup. I have menus for each activity. But when I press menu button, the menu does not appear. After doing some random trails I found that If I implement onCreateOptionsMenu in ActivityGroup then only menu appears. I am not able to execute onCreateOptionsMenu of Activity.
Please suggest how to use menu of Activity as I have many activities in single ActivityGroup and by implementing onCreateOptionsMenu in ActivityGroup is not the right way to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you roll with it:
In your ActivityGroup class onCreateOptionMenu() call the current `Activity` 's `onCreateOptionMenu()` i.e

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    Activity activity = getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
    return activity.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    Activity activity = getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
    return activity.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)
{
    Activity activity = getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
    return activity.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and in your individual `Activity`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.MENU_LOGOUT:
        Dialog.showToast(this, "message");
        return true;
    case R.id.MENU_HELP:
        break;
    case R.id.MENU_ABOUT:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and if you want any `Activity` without having any `Menu` just override these methods

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    return true;
}
```